# CWP Php Switcher

Tags: php, centos7, php-7, vps, centos-web-panel

VPS on my server, centos 7 and cwp (Centos Web Panel) board.
I'm coding Codeigniter 3.x project.
CWP There are php (5.5-7.1.9) options as php selector.
I need to get my php version to 7.x.
like here
[enter link description here](http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/php-selector)
is successfully completed.
but the php version remains at 5.6.
and is not loaded.

Do you have any problems with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you gone through their [forum](http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/) and search for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have done that thing years ago. First you need to update Php to new version than switch it to latest, it will take 10-15 minutes to show